# Retrieve binary representation of series?

Tags: python-polars

Polars has a `pl.Binary` datatype with very little documentation. I'd like to get the binary representation of values in a DataFrame, but it appears that the data type and the resulting binary casts are independent. For example:

```py
import polars as pl

pl.Series([1], dtype=pl.UInt16).cast(pl.Binary)[0].hex()
```

yields `b'\x31'` which corresponds to the character `'1'`. So it appears `pl.Binary` first casts as `Utf8`. Is there any way to convert the values to a series of Byte arrays representing the underlying dtypes?

---

*Rationale*: I have a pandas tool that I use to write dataframes into native [BCP native format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) for SQL Server and bulk-uploads them using `bcp.exe`. The result is table uploads that are typically 300x faster than `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`.

I'd like to implement something similar to polars without having to go through numpy (which my pandas implementation currently does), whereby I can cast to `np.void()` and perform a sum (fold) across columns to concatenate binary arrays. I'm looking to do something similar wtih polars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of the `Binary` data type as a Python [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) object. It's simply a sequence of UTF8 characters represented as unsigned 8-bit integers.

So in your case, representing an integer like `1` as a `Binary` object, it makes sense that it decodes into the string `'1'`.

For implementing your use case, I would suggest looking into the [Dataframe Interchange Protocol](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.__dataframe__.html). You can use it to get pointers to underlying buffers where you can find the actual data in memory. You can then read it or encode it any way you want.